# how to create instance methods in typescript object when the object is assigned value from LocalStorage

Tags: angular, typescript

I am Java developer but i am trying typescript to play around.

Here is my user object:

```
export class User
{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    email?: string;
    unit: string;
    street: string;
    postalcode: string;
    paymentmode: string;

    public isComplete(): boolean
    {
        if(this.id != null && this.email != null && this.isAddress()){ return true}
        else return false;
    }

    public isAddress(): boolean
    {
        if(this.street != null && this.postalcode != null){ return true}
        else return false
    }


}
```

and there another typescript...

```
var user = new User();
user = this.loginService.getLocalUser();
```

I assume the localStorage is parsed to user!

I am unable to access the isComplete method in this way

```
user.isComplete()
```

instead i need to use it as a static object

```
User.isComplete
```

My getLocaluser:

```
getLocalUser(): User {
        var user = new User();
        user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

        return user;
    }
```

How can i achieve it?

[image: Error]

Comment: You want to make your method static ?

Comment: Those _are_ instance methods

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isComplete()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Avar%20user%3A%20User%20%3D%20new%20User()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(user.isComplete())%3B

Comment: Are you creating a new instance? Like `var user = new User()`? From your example it looks like you're missing this part.

Comment: `user = this.loginService.getLocalUser();` can return you a quite different object.

Comment: Thanks @Jokester I have updated my question. Please refer and let me know if it wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Use this

```
let user = new User().deserialize(this.loginService.getLocalUser());
```

Now inside your `User` model add a `deserialize()` method

```
deserialize(input: any): User {
    let self: any = this;
    for (let prop in input) {
            self[prop] = input[prop];
    }
    return self;
}
```

What happens is when you call your web service and map it to your `User` object using `parse()` it's instance methods are not created because they do not reside in your `response` object what deserialize() does is create a new copy of `User` object and copies value from response one by one .

Answer (score 5):

Just instantiate the `User` class with the parsed JSON data retrieved from `localStorage`.

Change your `getLocalUser` method as follows:

```
getLocalUser(): User {
    let userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    let user = new User(userData);

    return user;
}
```

Now when you have new instance, you can normally use defined instance methods of the class:

```
let user = this.loginService.getLocalUser();
let isComplete = user.isComplete();

console.log(isComplete); // => true/false
```

Also, you've missed to put the constructor to the `User` class:

```
export class User
{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    // ...

    constructor(userData: any) {
        this.id = userData.id;
        this.name = userData.name;
        // ...
    }

    public isComplete(): boolean
    {
        if(this.id != null && this.email != null && this.isAddress()){ return true}
        else return false;
    }

    // the rest of the methods...

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The error originates from here `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));`

The object returned from this statement is NOT an object of type `User`, hence, does not have `isComplete` member method.

@rattlehand's solution should be sufficient for you. But the code became dynamic that way.

I however prefer the solution to be completely typed, as it is one important goal of using TS.

```
export interface User
{
    id: string;
    name?: string;
    ...
}

function isComplete(user: User) { 
    if (user.id != null && user.email != null ) { 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function getLocalUser(): User {
    var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) as User;
    return user;
}

var user = getLocalUser();
console.log(isComplete(user)); // true or false
```

Using an interface instead of a class for a model can be strange coming Java. It is adapted in most popular frameworks I've used those are written in TS e.g. Angular, RxJs. The same applies to DefinitelyTyped's definitions. There are of course cases when Class is the better solution. I'll leave the space for you to find out.

You can even go further to make `localStorage` strictly typed by creating a generic wrapper.

```
export class LocalStorageService {
    private storage = localStorage;

    get<T>(key: string): T {
        var serialized: string = this.storage.getItem(key);
        return serialized ? <T>JSON.parse(serialized) : undefined;
    }

    set<T>(key: string, data: T) {
        var serialized: string = JSON.stringify(data);
        this.storage.setItem(key, serialized);
    }

    remove(key: string) {
        this.storage.removeItem(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to do it this way:

```
var user = new User;

user.isComplete();
```

**After** you edit your question, if I understand you correctly, you need to use ***namespace*** and ***Triple-Slash Directives*** as following:
In first file, **a.ts** for example:

```
namespace myNameSpace{
    export class User
    {
        id: string;
        name: string;
        email?: string;
        unit: string;
        street: string;
        postalcode: string;
        paymentmode: string;

        public isComplete(): boolean
        {
            if(this.id != null && this.email != null && this.isAddress()){ return true}
            else return false;
        }

        public isAddress(): boolean
        {
            if(this.street != null && this.postalcode != null){ return true}
            else return false
        }
    }
}
```

In the second file. **b.ts** for example:

```
/// <reference path="a.ts" />
namespace myNameSpace{
    var user = new User();
    //user = this.loginService.getLocalUser(); //this function need to be checked in your environment
    user.isComplete();
}
```

Comment: it says isComplete() is not a function

Comment: When? During compilation?

Comment: Nope, while i run the program!

Comment: I think the OP's main concern was the question. he should have asked about the localstorage instead.

Comment: I update my answer. Hope I understand you correctly.

Comment: This is not targeting the main issue, which is that the JS object that gets parsed from the HTTP request is only an Object, and not a user, which does not contain the class methods obviously, he needs to construct an actual User object on response.

Answer (score 3):

How about simply:

```
getLocalUser(): User {
    return Object.assign(new User(), JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')));
}
```

where you (after [MDN: Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)):

> copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object.

and

> It will return the target object.

so you end up with freshly created instance of the `User` with all props from parsed JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var user = (<User>this.loginService.getLocalUser());
```